# Help with graph

Tags: graphics, graphs

[image])

I tried to do it, but it didn't work. You need to repeat the drawing on the picture, also add text (you can your own, I will edit).
[image]
My code:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=middle,
        axis line style={->},
        xlabel={},
        ylabel={},
        xtick={1, 2, 3},
        ytick=\empty,
        ymin=-2, ymax=2,
        xmin=0, xmax=3.5,
        every axis x label/.style={at={(axis description cs:1,0.5)},anchor=west},
        every axis y label/.style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,1)},anchor=south},
        no marks,
        clip=false,
        xticklabels={,,},
        yticklabels={,,},
        tick style={draw=none}
    ]

    % Sine wave, black
    \addplot+[domain=0:3, samples=200, smooth, black, thick] {sin(deg(2*pi*x))};
    % Cosine wave, green
    \addplot+[domain=0:3, samples=200, smooth, green!70!black, thick] {cos(deg(2*pi*x))};

    % Red vertical line
    \draw [red, thick] (axis cs:0,-2) -- (axis cs:0,2);
    % Gray horizontal line
    \draw [gray, thick] (axis cs:0,0) -- (axis cs:3.5,0);

    % Labels
    \node at (axis cs:1,0) [anchor=north] {1};
    \node at (axis cs:2,0) [anchor=north] {2};
    \node at (axis cs:3,0) [anchor=north] {3};

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome. // Please post your best attempt. Thank you

Comment: It's supposed to work the other way around: you post some code and people help you by editing it. You are much less likely to get help if you expect people to start from scratch, especially with non-Latin script. Your question is also not at all clear. What exactly is the problem? In what way didn't it work? Did you get an error? Did you get different output? 'It didn't work' gives us no clue about how to help you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please edit your question and add a minimal example of what you tried. This is not a just-do-it-for-me site, sorry. As is, your question has few possibility to be answered.

Comment: You should post what you tried. There are a lot of different ways to draw such a diagram, so it is essential that you show us which packages you want to use. Post a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows where you got stuck exactly. There are a lot of examples on this site and in the internet that can help you getting started.

Comment: I edited the post

Answer (score 2):

Just for indication, here's a way to do it. Remarks:

- What you're trying to do looks like Fourier synthesis to me. So just add the output of both functions.
- For simplicity I just copied your equations. There are certainly ways to put them as functions.
- Your periods/frequencies/wavelengths don't make sense. That's why the resultant (dashed, blue) differs. Adjust amplitudes and wavelenths and you'll obtain what you want.

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=middle,
        axis line style={->},
        xlabel={},
        ylabel={},
        xtick={1, 2, 3},
        ytick=\empty,
        ymin=-2, ymax=2,
        xmin=0, xmax=3.5,
        every axis x label/.style={at={(axis description cs:1,0.5)},anchor=west},
        every axis y label/.style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,1)},anchor=south},
        no marks,
        clip=false,
        xticklabels={,,},
        yticklabels={,,},
        tick style={draw=none}
    ]

    % Sine wave, black
    % changed amplitude
    \addplot+[domain=-1:3, samples=200, smooth, black, thick] {.333*cos(deg(2*pi*x))};
    % Cosine wave, green
    % changed frequency
    \addplot+[domain=-1:3, samples=200, smooth, green!70!black, thick] {cos(deg(2*pi*2/3*x))};
    % ~~~ sum of both ~~~~
   \addplot+[domain=-1:3, samples=200, smooth, blue, thick, dashed] {.333*cos(deg(2*pi*x)) + cos(deg(2*pi*2/3*x))};
   
   
    % Red vertical line
    \draw [red, thick] (axis cs:0,-2) -- (axis cs:0,2);
    % Gray horizontal line
    \draw [gray, thick] (axis cs:-1,0) -- (axis cs:3.5,0);

    % Labels
    \node at (axis cs:1,0) [anchor=north] {1};
    \node at (axis cs:2,0) [anchor=north] {2};
    \node at (axis cs:3,0) [anchor=north] {3};

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### P.S.

Here's a TeX-ish way to do it, which certainly is not recommended.

Define macros at the beginning, so change values just here:

```
...
\def\fa{.333*cos(deg(2*pi*x))}
\def\fb{1*cos(deg(2*pi*2/3*x))}
\def\fc{\fa + \fb}

\begin{document}
...
```

Replace your formulas by the macros:

```
    % Sine wave, black
    % changed amplitude
    \addplot+[domain=-1:3, samples=200, smooth, black, thick] {\fa};
    % Cosine wave, green
    % changed frequency
    \addplot+[domain=-1:3, samples=200, smooth, green!70!black, thick] {\fb};
    % ~~~ sum of both ~~~~
   \addplot+[domain=-1:3, samples=200, smooth, blue, thick, dashed] {\fc};
```

#### P.S.  P.S.

This is a choice of parameters, which is closer to your original (and now lost) screenshots:

```
\def\fa{.333*cos(deg(2*pi*x*5/8))}
\def\fb{1*cos(deg(2*pi*1*x/4))}
\def\fc{\fa + \fb}
```

[image: result2]

Comment: I would also like to understand how to shift the graph so that the three lines intersect at about 1.5 :)

Comment: It's a matter of chosing the right amplitudes and frequencies. Either you calculate them beforehand, or you do some trial-and-error, as I did, based on good guesses. // Try e.g. \def\fa{.333*cos(deg(2*pi*x*5/8))} and 
\def\fb{.8*cos(deg(2*pi*1*x/4.8))}